# Objective-c Set datepicker maximun date from another date picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I want to `setMaximumDate` with the second `datepicker` to the first date picker as the maximum date.
Even when I change the second `datepicker` I want it to be updated and put as maximum in the first `datepicker`

```
UIDatePicker firstPicker;
UIDatePicker secondPicker;
```

I tried this

```
[firstPicker setMaximumDate:[secondPicker date]];
```

But when I change the second datepicker the first is not limited to the second date.

Comment: When you select a date in the `secondPicker`, then set the `maximumDate` for the `firstPicker`.

Comment: Show the code where you handle the selection in the second date picker.

Comment: UIPicker is a little weird that way. I think you need to reload the picker somehow after you set the maxDate. [picker reload]; try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

```
[self.picker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateLabelFromPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then

```
- (IBAction)updateLabelFromPicker:(id)sender {
    [_firstPicker setMaximumDate:_secondPicker.date];
}
```